# If I’m sore, does that mean I haven’t fully recovered?

Tags: muscle, strength-training, muscle-soreness

To avoid overtraining, I try to fully recovery between weightlifting workouts.

When muscles are sore, does that mean they have not fully recovered yet?

Comment: Overtraining is probably much harder to get to than you think it is.

Comment: Maybe so, but I’m not looking to discuss the likelihood of overtraining, only whether soreness means I haven’t recovered.